# google analytics true unique visitors using login

Tags: google-analytics

I have a site which requires login to access. Is it possible for me to use the user's login ID to get Google Analytics to recognise that a user is not unique if they use a different browser or computer?

I'd have thought it should be possible to tell google who the user is based on their login ID rather than relying on a cookie.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite, but almost. If you use Universal Analytics you can [pass a client id to the function that creates the tracker](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#clientId), so Google Analytics can recognize the user. That needs to be a [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) which you user ID is probably not, so you'd need a way to transform the login ids into the UUID format.

A while ago I had a very short sneak preview into a new feature for Google Analytics Premium - there is (or will be) a cross-device-report which I think works based on user recognition via UUID (no idea if this will ever come to the free version, though).